# Java, delimiter

Tags: java, delimiter

I have this code for delimiters: `(":|\\s+")`.
I want the sign allowed like this: `(":")`, but if I use this the program does not work - it stops after the first question.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Salary
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int hour1, hour2, minute1, minute2, salary; 
        double totaly, totSalary, totHours, totMinutes, totDecMinutes;

        salary = 190;       

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        scan.useDelimiter(":|\\s+"); 

        System.out.println("Write the time when you startet working."
            + "Use the format (hh:mm).");

        hour1 = scan.nextInt();
        minute1 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Write the time when you stopped working."
            + "Use the formatet (hh:mm).");

        hour2 = scan.nextInt();
        minute2 = scan.nextInt();

        // Counts the number of workinghours.
        totHours = (hour2 - hour1);

        // Counts the number om workingminutes, decimal number
        totMinutes = (minute2 - minute1);
        totDecMinutes = totMinutes/60;

        // Counts the salary: total hours.
        totaly = totHours + totDecMinutes;
        totSalary = totaly*salary;

        System.out.printf("Din lön för idag blir: %.2f kr.", totSalary);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think (not sure though) a newline is interpreted as some combination of space. The delimiter used above delimits on either the **:** or one or more spaces. If I wrote **2:34** and then click enter to go to a newline, the scanner would delimit on the : giving 2 for the hour and then delimit on the newline character giving 34 for the minute. I am not sure how a newline gets translated to ASCII, and in any rate it varies with the Operating System.

That is why I prefer to use **Scanner.nextLine()** which returns the input from the rest of the line, excluding any line separator at the end. It is also easier to sanitize the user input (see example code below) as I can repeatedly ask for the user to provide a time if the previous time is not well-formed.

```
public class Salary
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int hour1, hour2, minute1, minute2, salary; 
    double totaly, totSalary, totHours, totMinutes, totDecMinutes;

    salary = 190;       

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Write the time when you startet working."
            + "Use the format (hh:mm).\n>> ");
    while (true) {
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        String[] parsed = s.split(":");
        if (s.split(":").length == 2) {
            try {
                hour1 = Integer.parseInt(parsed[0]);
                minute1 = Integer.parseInt(parsed[1]);
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Invalid input. Try again\n>> ");
    }

    System.out.print("Write the time when you stopped working."
            + "Use the formatet (hh:mm).\n>> ");
    while (true) {
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        String[] parsed = s.split(":");
        if (s.split(":").length == 2) {
            try {
                hour2 = Integer.parseInt(parsed[0]);
                minute2 = Integer.parseInt(parsed[1]);
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Invalid input. Try again\n>> ");
    }

    // Counts the number of workinghours.
    totHours = (hour2 - hour1);

    // Counts the number om workingminutes, decimal number
    totMinutes = (minute2 - minute1);
    totDecMinutes = totMinutes/60.0;

    // Counts the salary: total hours.
    totaly = totHours + totDecMinutes;
    totSalary = totaly*salary;

    System.out.printf("Din lön för idag blir: %.2f kr.", totSalary);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this.